# Regex to detect period at end of string, but not '...'

Tags: ruby, regex, string, oniguruma

Using a regex, how can I match strings that end with exactly one `.` as:

- `This is a string.`

but not those that end with more than one `.` as:

- `This is a string...`

I have a regex that detects a single `.`:

```
/[\.]{1}\z/
```

but I do not want it to match strings that end in `...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is a 'negative lookbehind' assertion:

```
(?<!\.)\.\z
```

This looks for a period at the end of a string *that isn't preceded by a period*. The other answers won't match the following string: `"."`

Also, you may need to look out for unicode ellipsis characters…
You can detect this like so: `str =~ /\u{2026}/`

Comment: Yep, I didn't realize but some of my strings have '..'. So this solution was the best for my use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
[^\.][\.]\z
```

You are looking for a string that before the last dot there is a char that is not a dot.

Comment: Does the `\.` need to be in `[]` ?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 yes, because you need to exclude a char - so you need a group of chars to exclude

Comment: I mean the final '.' match. Isn't `[\.]` the same as `[.]` which is the same as `\.`?

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` inside a character class, and the second character class _is_ redundant: `[^.]\.\z`

Comment: What if `str = '.'`?

Answer (score 0):

I like *Regexr* a lot!

Solution similar to Dekel:

```
[^.]+[.]
```

[Live demo](http://regexr.com/3ghcn)

Comment: I edited to include your solution within the body of the answer and avoid a _link only answer_, i hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: What about "my.cat" or "."? `[.]` instead of `\.` is OK, but I can't say I've seen it before.